# Form 1040 Line 77(Year 2014) is empty

Tags: united-states, taxes

Lat year I used TaxAct software to report my tax for the year 2014. At the final stage, the software asked me whether I would estimate the next year tax and pay it in advance. So I clicked yes and I have payed 4 times to IRS in the year 2015.

Now I still use TaxAct to prepare the tax for the year 2015. In somewhere, it asked me.
[image: tax]

Therefore I get the tax form 1040 from the drawer and look at it. But I found line 77 is empty.

Do I misunderstand the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is fine.  If line 77 from last year is empty, you should leave this question blank.

You made estimated tax payments in 2015.  But line 77 relates to a different way to pay the IRS.  When you filed your 2014 taxes, if you were owed a refund, and you expected to owe the IRS money for 2015, line 77 lets you say "Hey IRS, instead of sending me a refund for 2014, just keep the money and apply it to my 2015 taxes."  You can also ask them to keep a specified amount and refund the rest.  Either way this is completely optional.

It sounds like you didn't do that, so you don't fill in anything here.  The software should ask you in a different question about your estimated tax payments.