# About late payment on the date April 18 2016

Tags: united-states, taxes

[Here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/59323/form-1040-line-77year-2014-is-empty/59324#59324) is the corresponding thread. I used TaxAct to report my tax for 2015. Because I payed the estimated tax four times(quarterly), so I input the numbers. But afterwards, the system reminded me to input the next one.

The Date is 4/18/2016/ Haha, today is February 14, 2016.

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Your payment of 4/18/2016 is the final payment, not a (late) payment of _estimated_ tax. You are being asked "Did you make _another_ payment of _Estimated_ tax for 2015 after 1/15/2016 when the last installment of estimated tax for 2015 was due?"

Comment: @DilipSarwate, should I ignore it? Because 4/15/2016 is the last due date.

Comment: You don't need to do anything if you _didn't_ make any payments of _Estimated_ tax for 2015 after 1/15/2016. When you _file_ your tax return (by April 18, 2016) and pay any tax still due, that will not be a payment of estimated tax. If you are concerned about 4/15 versus 4/18 in the form shown, forget it.

Comment: See http://www.efile.com/tax-day-deadlines/ for a reason for the three-day shift...